# Only sign assemblies with strong name during release build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, continuous-integration, teamcity, assembly-signing

The scenario is: I'm building my solution with TeamCity, I'm not running the build account as an administrator; so I get problems with the strong name keys.

I know of a few solutions out there, like running the build as an administrator and registering the certificates in the proper container.

Is there anyway to sign the assemblies within a solution file only during a release build and not during a debug build. Or are there any similar solutions?

I think it is strange that there isn't a MSBuild parameter that can be set wether the assemblies should be signed or not. Because if you look at the csproj-files there is an option there for signed or not signed

Comment: There is a Msbuild Parameter: 

msbuild (YourSolution/Project) /p:SignAssembly=true /p:AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile=yourKey.snk

Answer (score 15):

Another option is to edit the project file. By default if you enable assembly signing in Visual Studio it will be used for all build configurations. The project file contains an element like the following.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
  <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>YourKeyFile.pfx</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you only want to sign the assemblies during a specifc build configuration, such as RELEASE. You can put the `<SignAssembly>` and `<AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>` in the PropertyGroup element with the Condition that identifies your build configuration.

So if you want to sign your assembly during a release build, you can change your project file to the following.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <!-- other element of this PropertyGroup -->
  <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>      
  <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>YourKeyFile.pfx</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Note:** When you change your project file, to the following. you cannot change the signing settings of the Project Properties in Visual Studio. That means in Visual Studio is signing of the assembly disabled, also if you change the build configuration in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution where the assembly is signed in `Release` configuration, but not in Debug configuration. It uses the signing facilities from the project, not using the `[AssemblyKeyFile]` attribute. It's basically the same as [Jehof's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7926070/806690) but in other words.

1. Set up the project for signing in the *Signing* tab in project preferences.
2. Unload the project, and edit it in the XML editor. Locate the `SignAssembly` property. Move that property into the two configuration dependent property groups. In the Debug configuration, set the property to false.

This will look something like this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <!-- ... -->
    <SignAssembly>false</SignAssembly>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Visual Studio works correctly even when changing build configurations, with the exception of the *Sign the assembly* check box in the *Signing* tab. I tested with Visual Studio 2008.

Cave-Eats:

- You need to remove the `[AssemblyKeyFile]` attribute for this to work.
- If you have `[InternalsVisibleTo]` attributes, you need to maintain two versions, like this:

```c#
#if DEBUG
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyLib.NUnit")]
#else
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyLib.NUnit, PublicKey=<your public key>")]
#endif
```

In other words, `MyLib.NUnit` must also be signed in `Release` configuration.

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 doesn't seem to support making the `SignAssembly` property conditional this way. I have lots of `FileLoadException` at application start up since Visual Studio 2008 signs one of the libraries when it shouldn't, and vice versa. I then need to rebuild the application. Unsure whether later versions of Visual Studio expose this behavior, too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use preprocessor directives:

```
#if SIGN
//Only the Release build is signed
#pragma warning disable 1699  //We can't use the compiler switch
[assembly: AssemblyKeyName("KeyContainerName")]
#pragma warning restore 1699
#endif
```

Then define the `SIGN` symbol in the Release configuration.

You must install the key into a key container using `sn.exe`.  Alternatively, you can use `[AssemblykeyFile]` to specify a path.

The `#pragma` suppresses [this warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh3fc3x0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Where would i put the preprocessor directives? I think it strange that there isn't a MSBuild parameter that can set wheter the assemblies shuld be signed or not. Because if you look at the csproj-files there is an option there for signed or not signed.

Comment: Anywhere; typically in AssemblyInfo.cs.  This might also be possible with MSBuild; I'm not sure.